# Psychological research on memorability of passwords?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, hci

There are lots of ad-hoc rules that people are happy to propose about passwords, such as:

- Pick a phrase you can remember easily, and then use the initial letters.
- A random short sequence of letters, numbers and symbols.
- A sequence of random common words (like XKCD's "battery correct horse staple").

There is also a pile of computer security research on what passwords are hard to crack.

It seems like a pretty simple empirical question to say what is the best password scheme for any given desired strength.

**Can anyone point me to any research about the ease of memorizing passwords generated according to various rules?**

Comment: One study is Yan, J., Blackwell, A., Anderson, R. & Grant, A. (2004). Password memorability and security: Empirical results. Security & Privacy, IEEE, 2, 25-31. [PDF](https://www-test.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-500.pdf)

Comment: Consider yourself pointed http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=+Password+memorability

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is some empirical evidence that passphrases are easier to remember than either random passwords (not surprising) or user-selected short passwords after standard advice to use mix of upper and lower and avoid words.

http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/jeff.yan/#exp

Thanks Jeff for the pointer in a comment (same Jeff?).

> J. Yan, A. Blackwell, R. Anderson and A. Grant. The memorability and
>   security of passwords -- some empirical results. University of
>   Cambridge, Computer Laboratory Technical Report No. 500, 2000. (see
>   also Hungarian translation). [PDF](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-500.pdf)
>
> J. Yan, A. Blackwell, R. Anderson and A. Grant. Password Memorability
>   and Security: Empirical Results. IEEE Security & Privacy, Vol. 2 No.
>   5, 2004. [PDF](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/jeff.yan/jyan_ieee_pwd.pdf)

the above is reprinted as:

> J. Yan, A. Blackwell, R. Anderson and A. Grant. The Memorability and
>   Security of Passwords. Refereed book chapter in Security and
>   Usability: Designing Secure Systems that People Can Use (ed. by Lorrie
>   Cranor and Simson Garfinkel), OReilly & Associates, USA, 2005.

Comment: hah, definitely not the same Jeff! interesting studies; i've edited to include the citations directly